# Password with special character in the scripted Jenkins pipeline for 7z command

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I am working on a scripted Jenkins pipeline. I have stored a secret in Credential plugin. I want to use that secret when creating an achieve using 7z.
Here is my code:

```
stage('Zip and Encrypt Artifacts') {
   withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'encryption_key', variable: 'SHARED_PASSWORD')]) {
      archive = report.replace(".txt",".7z")
      sh "7z a -p${SHARED_PASSWORD} -mhe ${archive} ${report}"
      sh "rm ${report}"
   }

}
```

This code works with simple password. But, it fails with strong password.
What is your suggestion? How should I change the `sh` command?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quote all your variables:

```
    sh '''
        7z a "-p${SHARED_PASSWORD}" -mhe "${archive}" "${report}"
        rm "${report}"
    '''
```

Note that you need to use single quotes around the script so you can use double quotes inside it. You have to use double quotes in the shell command so that variables will be expanded.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar your former answer worked. this one I mean:
`sh "7z a -mhe '${archive}' '${report}' -p'${SHARED_PASSWORD}'"` 
Then, I tested your new edition. It didn't work.
I thought that the problem is with `"-p${SHARED_PASSWORD}"`. So, I tested `-p"${SHARED_PASSWORD}"`. It didn't work.

I moved `-p` to the end of the line and it didn't work as well.

Anyway, thanks for your help and I am glad that I was refreshing this page non-stop.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how the variables are substituted. I thought they were just put in the environment and then substituted by the shell, but it sounds like Jenkins is doing its own substitutions.